# Can I use windows 8 to install and use Microsoft Hololens?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens

I need to work on unity 3D and Hololens to predict and map the movement of a machine.I wanted to ask is it possible to use Hololens and trace the movement of a machine by using windows 8? I would also appreciate if anyone could help me with the total installation procedure of how to install and use Hololens since I am new to it.I found some installation guides but that requires Windows 10 and since I have windows 8, anything related to it such as which packages to install, would be very useful.Thank you everyone for your time.

Best Regards

Safayet

Comment: Considering [this](https://pterneas.com/2016/03/31/hololens-system-requirements/), Yes you can.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but the hardware requirements specified in your link states that it requires Windows 10 Pro so I am confused whether with Windows 8.1, can I install Hololens or not as according to the article in the link my hardware system requirements does not match as I do not have windows 10 Pro ..

Comment: @Safayet Windows 8.1 is no longer supported. Upgrading to Windows 10 was free for quite a while. That doesn't mean you can't use Windows 8.1. Unsupported versions won't be mentioned on new product docs though, nor will they get driver and software updates.

Comment: Thank you Panagiotis for your reply...I am still hopeful that there might be a workaround..:)

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use windows 8 to install and use Microsoft Hololens?

**No**, you can't.

To build for Hololens you need UWP and UWP needs the requirements below:

- Unity 5.2 or later
- A Windows 10 Pro, Enterprise, or Education (The Home edition does not support Hyper-V)
- Visual Studio 2015 RTM, (the minimum version is 14.0.23107.0). Please
  note that earlier versions, for example Visual Studio RC, are not
  supported in Unity 5.2.
- You’ll also need to install the Windows 10 SDK.
- 8 GB of RAM or more

The source for this information from [*Unity's blog*](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/09/09/windows-10-universal-apps-in-unity-5-2/).  In short, you can't because the SDK requires Windows 10.

Comment: Unity 5.2 is literally the bare, bottom-scraping minimum. I wouldn't even *think* of using a version less than 5.6, and given some of the changes in the last 2 years, nothing less than 2018.3 due to QOL improvements in the engine. If you're from the future, then 2019.3 if it is available. *Always* go with the latest version available for new projects unless you know something specific will be a problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply...I also read somewhere that with Windows 8 it is possible but I think it might not work..It is not possible for me to upgrade to Windows 10 and so looking for a workaroud..Thank you again for the reply..

Comment: I am not absolutely sure, but if you have a device and thus don't need the emulator, it might be sufficient to install Windows 10 Home. Hyper-V comes into play when deploying to the emulator. If you work with Unity you should try to do the most part of the development in the [simulator](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2016/09/29/introducing-holographic-emulation/)

Comment: Thank you Kay..I want to know that without deploying to the emulator can I use windows 8 for the development part like spatial mapping of the area ?Thank you for your reply once again.

Comment: @Safayet While I will wait for Kay to answer that, the answer is no like I mentioned. You need Windows 10 to develop for hololens. It will always be no and it looks like MS did that to make you upgrade to Windows 10. Finally, you don't even need to upgrade to Windows 10. Install virtual machine (VMware) then install Windows 10 on it for testing your hololens app. It would be slower but it avoid wiping out your Windows 8. You can also do dual boot which I recommend over vm.

Comment: Thank you @Programmer for your reply.I think I will switch to virtual machine...Thanks again for your response...